# react-native-snap-carousel is very laggy for large data

Tags: react-native

I am using `react-native-snap-carousel` to swipe through images. When there is like 0-10 images it's working fine, but otherwise it's very laggy. I tried the optimization methods but didn't fix it.

*Here is my implementation* (`selectedItems` is the data I have):

```
const renderItem = useCallback(
  ({ item, index }) => {
  return (
    <CarouselImage
      ad={ad}
      item={item}
      index={index}
      showImage={showImage}
    />
  );
},
[ad, showImage]);



return ad?.videos?.length > 0 || ad?.images?.length > 0 ? (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Carousel
        initialNumToRender={selectedItems.length}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
        ref={carouselRef}
        swipeThreshold={5}
        itemWidth={wp(375)}
        data={selectedItems}
        sliderWidth={wp(375)}
        enableMomentum={false}
        lockScrollWhileSnapping
        renderItem={renderItem}
        onSnapToItem={(index) => setActiveSlide(index)}
      />
      <Pagination
        activeOpacity={1}
        tappableDots={true}
        animatedDuration={100}
        inactiveDotScale={0.4}
        inactiveDotOpacity={0.4}
        carouselRef={carouselRef}
        dotStyle={styles.dotStyle}
        activeDotIndex={activeSlide}
        dotsLength={selectedItems.length}
        containerStyle={styles.pagination}
        dotContainerStyle={styles.dotContainer}
        inactiveDotStyle={styles.inactiveDotStyle}
      />
    </View>
```

Is there something I am missing. Also, is there an alternative library that runs better with large data ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative library: [react-native-banner-carousel-updated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-banner-carousel-updated)

I'm using this with more than 20 images and it's works fine.

Comment: I think it has to do with the state I am updating each time I scroll the component is re-rendered. Do you have ant idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the optimization you've tried is what is described in the react-native-snap-carousel library docs...

I too found that every swipe was causing my screen's component to re-render.
You might be thinking...

> I think it has to do with the state I am updating each time I scroll the component is re-rendered. Do you have ant idea how to solve this ?

To prevent the re-rendering of your `<Carousel ... />` component, the optimization that you want to look at is to utilize `React.memo()`

Try refactoring your `<Carousel ... />` component to a new component file, something like this...

Gallery.js

```
import React from "react";
import CarouselCardItem, { SLIDER_WIDTH } from "./CarouselCardItem";
import { ALL_RECIPES } from "../config/Recipe/allRecipes";
import Carousel from "react-native-snap-carousel";

const Gallery = ({ carouselRef, selectedItems, setActiveSlide}) => {
  console.log("render"); // <== This will render only when props change (ie. the ref - which should not change, or you pass fresh data - in which case you want it to re-render)
  return (
      <Carousel
          initialNumToRender={selectedItems.length}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
          ref={carouselRef}
          swipeThreshold={5}
          itemWidth={wp(375)}
          data={selectedItems} // <== selectedItems could be passed in as prop, or from app state
          sliderWidth={wp(375)}
          enableMomentum={false}
          lockScrollWhileSnapping
          renderItem={renderItem}
          onSnapToItem={(index) => setActiveSlide(index)}
      />
  );
};
const GalleryMemo = React.memo(Gallery);
export default GalleryMemo;
```

Then in your screen file, use it
`<GalleryMemo carouselRef={carouselRef} selectedItems={selectedItems} setActiveSlide={setActiveSlide}/>`